# Указатели на функции. Тип void*

Tags: c, указатели

Сразу скажу, что предоставленный мною код является неполным. Если вы не поняли суть моего вопроса и причиной послужило - "неполный код", то в конце я предоставлю ссылку на пример с полным кодом.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dbleInt(void *a) {
    *((int*) a) *= 2;
}


void dbleDouble(void *a) {
    *((double*) a) *= 2.0;
}


void map(void *arr, unsigned num, size_t size, void (*fun)(void *)) {
    unsigned i;
    char *ptr = (char*) arr;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        fun((void*) (ptr + i*size)); /* !!!!!! */
    }
}


int main () {

    return 0;
}
```

Данную строку

```
fun((void*) (ptr + i*size));
```

я  перепишу таким образом

```
fun(ptr + i*size);
```

Как правильнее писать и есть ли разница между этими двумя записями?

p.s 3 по счету пример от начала https://learnc.info/c/function_pointers.html

Comment: Код по приведенной вами ссылке изобилует ненужными приведениями типов, а также содержит довольно банальные ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формально "правильно" и так, и так. Однако можно порекомендовать стараться писать код, который настолько *типонезависим*, насколько это возможно. То есть в рамках этого совета следует стараться избегать ненужных упоминаний имен типов в коде. В частности, это означает, что следует избегать ненужных явных приведений типов ("кастов"). В вашем случае совершенно не нужными являются приведения типа в

```
char *ptr = (char*) arr;
```

и в

```
fun((void*) (ptr + i*size));
```

Например, ошеломляюще монструозная конструкция, использованная в другом примере по вашей ссылке

```
float (**menu)(float, float) = NULL;
...
menu = (float(**)(float, float)) malloc(4*sizeof(float(*)(float, float)));
```

может быть "почищена" до существенно более элегантного и обозримого состояния

```
float (**menu)(float, float) = malloc(4 * sizeof *menu);
```

P.S. К "указателям на функции", упомянутых вами в заголовке вопроса, данный вопрос не имеет прямого отношения.

Comment: может быть дадите пару уроков, как правильно озаглавливать вопросы, то уже второй раз слышу о неправильности действия сего.

Comment: @non_grata заголовок должен отражать суть вопроса. У Вас вопрос не связан с указателями на функции.

Comment: @Croessmah Вы знаете ответ на вопрос, вам легко рассуждать. Для меня же данная тема является новой, когда я ставил вопрос, я не знал для чего нужно дополнительно писать void*, как и не знал того, что это может быть сделано специально в новой для меня теме, отсюда я посчитал целесобразным поставить вопрос именно так.

Answer (score 1):

Неявное преобразование в `void*` разрешено, поэтому разницы не будет.
Как писать правильнее - это скорее вопрос вкусоцветостиля, т.е. однозначный ответ Вы вряд ли получите.